# How to implement pagination In AngularStrap(Bootstrap)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

I am using Angular Strap in my design. While I try to implement pagination, I cannot find any documentation or related posts of Pagination in Angular Strap.

How is pagination implemented in Angular Strap ?

Comment: do you need it for a table?

Comment: No, I am trying to use in normal view not a table